# Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' When trying to sort

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I am trying to sort a 2D array of custom struct, `id` is optional, but when I try to unwrap them I get another error: `Cannot assign value of type '()' to subscript of type '[SomeObject]'`

```
for x in 0..<tableData.count {
   tableData[x] = tableData[x].sort(by: {$0.id! > $1.id!})
}
```

What can I do here?

Comment: Change `sort` to `sorted`

Answer (score 0):

`sort` is a **mutating method** and sorts the collection **in-place**, i.e. the return type of this method is `Void`.

So, there is no need to store the result of `sort` back to `tableData`, i.e.

```
for x in 0..<tableData.count {
    tableData[x].sort(by: {$0.id! > $1.id!})
}
```

Make sure that `tableData` is a `var`.